# Got error when I push Heroku: remote: ! No default language could be detected for this app

Tags: heroku

I ran `git push heroku master` successfully before a couple of times. However, This time when I have a new project and try to use it, it doesn't work. The error I checked is from here:

```
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:        HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
```

then the result is:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/heroku-proj1.git'
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using legacy PHP in your project, you will need a index.php file and Heroku will automatically build your project for you.

If you are using python Django or Flask then you are required to create requirements.txt in your main directory. This file contains all the dependencies in your app. This can be done by using the command(run it in main directory) -> pip3 freeze > requirements.txt

You will also need a to create a runtime.txt In this  you will need to declare the exact version of python in following format -> python-3.9.2

You will also need to install gunicorn in your app,especially if it's a flask app. Gunicorn is a Web Server Gateway Interface (WSGI) server implementation that is commonly used to run Python web applications. Use "pip install gunicorn" command. Then you will need a procfile. The procfile contains the command line for starting your application on heroku. It is a simple text file but don't create a specific txt file just create it using any text editor like vs code.

In the procfile, write the following -> web: gunicorn app:app
(second "app" is name of your python routing file ex. - app.py)

Now you can try pushing it to heroku. For ref, use below cmd commands to do all the process from start to finish:

#download heroku cli
#create virtual environment in the app folder
py -3 -m venv name_of_venv

#activate venv
name_of_venv\Scripts\activate

#install flask
pip install flask

#go to app folder and type
set FLASK_APP=file_name.py

#to set debugger environment type
set FLASK_ENV=development

########################now to upload to heroku using heroku cli

#install gunicorn in the app folder (venv active)
pip isntall gunicorn

#create Procfile to tell heroku that we are using gunicorn
#Procfile does not have any extension
web: gunicorn app:name_of_server_python_file (without .py extension)

#create requirements.txt file
pip freeze > requirements.txt

#for pushing your code to heroku use git
#turn on git
git init

#add everything from app folder type-
git add .

#commit changes
git commit -m"initial commit"

#push to heroku, first login to heroku, type-
heroku login

#create app
heroku create app_name / heroku create (name automatically created)

#push code to heroku
git push heroku main

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the suggestion. Yes, the problem happened on PHP although it's different from installing. It needs me to add a PHP file in my folder to point out the HTML. That is, in my folder, I had only: CaloCalc.js, Calories-cal.html, style.css. I added a PHP file called index.PHP with only one word inside: 
and it works.